# Virtualbox vboxdrv 6.0.14 won't compile on kernel 5.4.1

Tags: virtualbox

After a recent update to mainline kernel 5.4.1, I'm no longer able to build vboxdrv with

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

I get a number of similar errors like

````
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘__attribute__’
```
against
compiler_attributes.h @ 200
cdefs.h @ 1169
````

Comment: Expected with a brand-new kernel; here's a fix: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/virtualbox-broken-virtualbox-fixed%3B-kernel-5-4-1-a-4175665260/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18945) is the upstream Virtualbox bug report that deals with various breakages of Linux 5.4 including the one you mentioned. It has been fixed in Virtualbox 6.1-rc1 and backported to the 5.2 branch. Unfortunately this might not be available as binary packages in all distributions that ship (test) versions of newer kernels. Debian Buster users might want to look at [this](https://people.debian.org/%7Elucas/virtualbox-buster/) special repo.